# Flexbox fill remaining space

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am currently developing a three column UI using flexbox. I need to allow the containing to fill the empty space on the screen. I am using:  `flex-direction: row;`

Most of the solutions out there I have come across all use `flex-direction: column;` which doesn't help in my situation as it throws the design out of the window.

I have set the height property: `height: 100%;` on the container. And have added `flex-grow: 1;` to all of the columns but that has not expanded the container to fill the remaining space.

[image: Columns]

That is what the UI looks like at the moment. The green at the bottom is a fixed height footer that needs to go below the container.

Here is what the containers CSS (using react *styled-components*) looks like:

```
export const PrimaryContainerStyled = styled.div`
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.colors.surface};
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.typography.onSurface};
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

And one of the columns look like the following:

```
export const MainColumnStyled = styled.div`
  flex-grow: 1;
  order: 2;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 10px 50px 100px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 10px
    30px 60px -30px;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.typography.onSurface};
`;
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get the container to fill the empty space but not overflow the footer?

Comment: Go to the container which you want to fill the remaining space, let's suppose it's the one in the middle and add this property but make sure your parent container is displayed as flex too:

`flex: 1 1 auto;`

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work. I need the entire container to fill the space. Not one of the columns within the container.

Comment: Can you create a working demo of your code?

Comment: Could you be more specific to what needs to take up the remaining space, and is it width or height of the page or inside the columns?

Comment: Did you try using `flex: 1` ?